# MySQL can execute SQL Server can't execute why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

My SQL command is working correctly in MySQL but I can't execute in SQL Server how can I fix?

SQL command is

```
SELECT FLIGHT.Flight_name, AVG(FARE.Amount)
FROM FLIGHT, FARE
WHERE FLIGHT.Flight_number = FARE.Flight_number
GROUP BY FARE.Amount;
```

My Tables are

FLIGHT TABLE

| Flight_number | Weekdays | Flight_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 1.Flight |
| 2 | 6 | 2.Flight |
| 3 | 3 | 3.Flight |
| 4 | 7 | 4.Flight |
| 5 | 4 | 5.Flight |
| 6 | 10 | 6.Flight |
| 7 | 4 | 7.Flight |
| 8 | 9 | 8.Flight |
| 9 | 4 | 9.Flight |
| 10 | 7 | 10.Flight |

FARE TABLE

| Flight_number | Fare_code | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3077 |
| 1 | 2 | 1230 |
| 1 | 3 | 3352 |
| 2 | 1 | 2628 |
| 2 | 2 | 2802 |
| 2 | 3 | 1434 |
| 3 | 1 | 2316 |
| 4 | 1 | 3112 |
| 4 | 2 | 3275 |
| 4 | 3 | 3380 |
| 5 | 1 | 2782 |
| 6 | 1 | 1270 |
| 6 | 2 | 2798 |
| 6 | 3 | 1833 |
| 6 | 4 | 3615 |
| 7 | 1 | 3842 |
| 8 | 1 | 2994 |
| 8 | 2 | 2799 |
| 9 | 1 | 1616 |
| 9 | 2 | 3314 |
| 9 | 3 | 2474 |
| 9 | 4 | 2084 |
| 10 | 1 | 2129 |
| 10 | 2 | 1850 |
| 10 | 3 | 3185 |
| 10 | 4 | 2847 |

SQL server error says

> Column 'FLIGHT.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not
> contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: `GROUP BY FLIGHT.Flight_name`

Comment: Why will it not execute?  Are you getting an error and what is it?  There are differences  between the 2 RDBMS

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server use different SQL dialects, use the error to work out which bit of SQL isn't valid for SQL Server and google for the correct SQL.

Comment: You need to group by all non-aggregated columns. Aside: you should use proper join syntax `FROM FLIGHT JOIN FARE ON FLIGHT.Flight_number = FARE.Flight_number`

Comment: Evolve! No one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). Develop good habits.

Comment: _command is working correctly in MySQL_ actually should be _expected to raise an error, but instead returns some random result_.

Comment: So the error tells you *exactly* what you need to do to fix it? And using the SQL Server documentation for `group by` will answer any questions. As an aside, you are currently grouping by `Flight.Amount` and then averaging `Flight.Amount` but thats not going to give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: Your query is malformed. You are grouping by `FARE.Amount` but forgot to aggregate the column `FLIGHT.Flight_name`. The result is unpredictable. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everybody mentioned in the comments, just to write down the answer:

```
SELECT FLIGHT.Flight_name, AVG(FARE.Amount)
FROM FLIGHT
JOIN FARE ON FLIGHT.Flight_number = FARE.Flight_number
GROUP BY FLIGHT.Flight_name;
```